# Font collections names unlocalized in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, fonts

I'm getting all collections using `[[NSFontManager sharedFontManager] collectionNames]`, but I see some untranslated strings (such as "com.apple.AllFonts"). There is a way to localize them? I see that Font Book does translate them successfully. Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Thanks,

—Albe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple prefixes all of its internal collection names with "com.apple", probably to avoid conflicts. Depending on what you're doing, you could:

- Skip any collection name that begins with "com.apple" -- they're not collections created by the user.
- If a collection begins with "com.apple", split it and just get the last part of the name. Something like `if ([name hasPrefix:@"com.apple"]) name = [[name componentsSeparatedByString:@"."] objectAtIndex:2];` would work.

Comment: This only works for English. If the locale of your system is different, then they would still be wrong.